# When table has no primary key, @Id in @Entity only works within a transaction, not over multiple transactions?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I wondered if for the `@Id` annotation to work the table in the database needs to have a primary key. (The same for an `@ManyToOne` annotation and a foreign key, but I have not studied this situation yet).

In the database there is a table `foo`, which has no primary key, just 2 columns, `id` and `name`.

In Java there is an `@Entity Foo` with 2 properties: `@Id id` and `String name`.

In persistence.xml `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` is not `create`; the tables are already there.

When I save 2 `Foo`s with the same `id`in the same transaction, Hiberate protests: javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session.

So is it true that Hibernate takes over what a primary key in the database does
 (except for the index)?

But when I save the 2 `Foo`s in 2 transactions apart, they are saved to the database, so Hiberate's `@Id` does not work as a primary key!

Is this intentional that `@Id` only works within the same transaction?

The entity and transactions in Java are:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    // <init>s and getters and setters


public class EntityTests

    private String name;
    @Test
    public void test2() throws Exception {
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

        Foo foo=new Foo(1l,"bar");
        entityManager.persist(foo);

        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.close();

        entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

        Foo foo2=new Foo(1l,"baz");
        entityManager.persist(foo2);

        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.close();
    }
```

In the database we see:

```
sql> select*from foo;
ID | NAME
1  | bar
1  | baz
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation for identifiers in hibernate it says that they assume that the corresponding db column(s) are *unique, not null and immutable* so when you already have database tables then you need to make sure the corresponding identifier columns in the tables follow those requirements

[Hibernate doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers)